# Erlang cluster synchronization issues

Tags: erlang, beam

I have an erlang cluster of 4 nodes running on different hosts. I recently encountered an issue with the cluster in a way that beam process is running in one of the nodes but the application was not running. I could see that my OTP application was still holding client connections. The client connections are tcp connection.

Every node was able to ping the others but this node appeared to have stopped to other nodes.

Very weird but pretty much the same thing happened. Do you have any clue what might be wrong with them.

Can tcp retransmissions cause this?

Comment: There is very little context and information in this question. Add more details and be more specific about things such as: "4 nodes" (are these erlang nodes running in the same machine, 4 different machines, etc.), "application was not running" (I guess you mean an OTP application here, is this so?), "holding client connections" (what clients? what type of connection? TCP?), and so on.

Comment: @juan.facorro thank you for suggesting. I edited the question with relevant detials.